Test Data parameterization in TOSCA
I have a Test case in TOSCA.
The Test is to add 10 products to cart in one execution. In the next run, I need to run the same test with different 10 different products and so on. I have a total of 5k test products. How to achieve this in Tricentis TOSCA?

Set the repetition buffer to 500. Set the count buffer to 1.
First of all create a folder inside the test case and set the Repetition value as {B[repetition]}. This will execute the same test case 500 times.
Go to test case design and create a test sheet. Add 500 attributes named ProductSet1, ProductSet2 and so on. Under ProductSet1, add 10 Products named Product1, Product2 and so on. Same needs to be done for other ProductSets also.
Create a Do loop inside the above folder. Under Loop, add the test case for adding the product to the cart. For ProductSet1, use {XL[ProductSet{B[count]}]} and then add cell values by mapping the instances to them. Also, increase the count by 1 here.
Under Condition, count should not exceed 500.
